# Radius of Uniform Convergence -- $\sum a_nz^n$ converges on every closed interval within $(-R,R)$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, power-series, uniform-convergence

In my Analysis III course, we have recently proven the following result.

> If the power series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nz^n$$ has radius of convergence
>   $R$, then the series converges *uniformly* on $\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|<a\}$ for every $a<R$, i.e. on every closed interval $[-a,a]\subseteq(-R,R)$.

We then went on to say that although the power series converges on every closed interval subset of $(-R,R)$, it **does not converge uniformly** on the open interval $(-R,R)$ itself. But how can this be? If we can choose $a<R$ to be arbitrarily close to $R$, then surely this is equivalent to saying that it converges on the open interval $(-R,R)$ itself? Perhaps I've misunderstood what an open interval actually is - I've always thought of $(-2,2)$, for example, to be the interval obtained by making a closed interval $[-a,a]$ get arbitrarily close to when $a=2$, in a limiting way.

The only difference I can think of is that when we consider $[-a,a]$ where $a<R$, there is always a 'gap' between $a$ and $R$, no matter how close to $R$ we get; whereas there are no 'gaps' when considering the open interval. But I still can't see how this shows that we do not have uniform convergence.

Comment: Take for instance the series $1+x+x^2+\dots$, which has radius $1$ and converges to $\frac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$. It can't converge uniformly on $(-1,1)$ because the sum is unbounded near $1$. Same argument as in my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258787/is-f-n-uniformly-convergent-on-0-infty

Comment: It converges on (-R,R) but the convergence may fail to be uniform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniform convergence means that for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$, such that for all $n\ge n_0$ and $x\in\left[-a,a\right]$,
$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k z^k-S\left(x\right)\right|<\varepsilon$$
where $S\left(x\right)$ is the limit function. The problem is that $n_0$ depends on $a$ (but not on $x$). So, theoretically, when you take $a$ close enough to $R$, the value of $n_0$ for a given $\varepsilon$ may tend to $\infty$, and thus the convergence may not be uniformly.